# wp_dropdown_categories how to access name displayed

Tags: wordpress

I have a nice working wp_dropdown_categories that displays what I want.

Looks like this:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/category/"+$categorySearch" />
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select a Category&name=categorySearch'); ?>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

For output I get:  ?categorySearch=#

But I really want the slug.  I've googled this and seen functions that extend the walker, but I don't understand them.  Is there an easier way to grab the slug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A huge thank you Dhanuka for pointing me to get_categories.  I just plugged in the code from codex and it worked fine.

```
<select onchange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
<option value=""><?php echo esc_attr(__('Select a Category')); ?></option>
<?php
    $categories = get_categories('orderby=name&name=categorySearch');
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $option = '<option value="/category/'.$category->category_nicename.'">';
    $option .= $category->cat_name;
    $option .= ' ('.$category->category_count.')';
    $option .= '</option>';
    echo $option;
    }
?>
</select>
```

I thought I would still have to deal with an unwanted /?categorySearch=

What removed that string from the url?

Also I didn't need to change anything to get it to work - thought I would need to replace nicename with slug,

Comment: someone down voted my answer. can you please upvote it ? I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

use get_categories() instead of wp_dropdown_categories(). post your code so I can help you